# Connecting to remote Active Directory using C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, remote-server

I want to connect to a ActiveDirectory using c#.

I need to be able to connect to an DC which I can only resolve using an IP Address (which I have).

The next step is to find a computer in the DC address leases to resolve the IP address of a computername entered by a user.

Can someone give me a heads up?

I should be using

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC-IpAddress");
directoryEntry.Path = "LDAP://(What should I enter here for "Address Leases"?);
```

then I need a returned value which gives me the IP-Address of target Computer.

Hope you folks can help me out a bit.

FYI: The DHCP Server is installed on the target DC. just in case ;)

Comment: This sure sounds a lot like you're confusing LDAP with DNS.

Comment: I could be mistakes, yes. Lets say I need the DNS-record from the DC and then find my value..

Comment: If you just want to resolve a name, `Dns.GetHostEntry()` will give you the IP Addresses associated with a DNS name.

Comment: The problem is that its not "just resolve à name", I need to resolve it through à remote DC. So I am unable to use my local dns server. The target computer is connected to à different DC than I am on. Although I do have à connection with the DC I need the pc-adress from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this  link VB project which is contains in the  forth section a method that  Listing all computers in the Active Directory .. may it helpful for you

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19689/Working-with-Active-Directory-in-VB-NET

Comment: Thx but this does not get me further then getting an OU or domain relationship.

Comment: if your main problem in the connection to specific DC remotely you need to an authenticated connection as the follow

Comment: var d = Domain.GetDomain(new DirectoryContext(
            DirectoryContextType.Domain,
            domainStr,
            Username,
            Password));

Comment: you may need to check out this link .
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374773/cant-connect-to-ad-without-specifically-connecting-to-a-dc

Comment: and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015407/determine-current-domain-controller-programmatically  you will read related problem and it is answer